# MongoDb nodejs connectTimeoutMS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can someone show an example how setting connectTimeoutMS to different value gives different results?

App starts:

```
   var myDB = null;          
   var options = { server: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: 5000 }}};
                    MongoClient.connect(CONFIG.connectionString,options, function(err, db) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }

                        db.on('error', function(err){
                            console.error('can not establish connection');
                        });

                        myDB = db;

                    });
```

Later I stop the mongo service (on windows) and execute code which uses

```
myDB.collection('someCollection').find({}).toArray(function(err){
    console.log('never called after stoping mongo service. Shouldnt it call with err argument?',err);
});
```

1. I would expect a  callback inside 'toArray' be executed based on the `connectTimeoutMS` property. Why isn't it called?
2. If `connectTimeoutMS` is meant for something else, how can I see different effect when I set it to different values.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the difference between `connectTimeoutMS` and `socketTimeoutMS`. From the [Node.js driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html),

> connectTimeoutMS=ms :How long a connection can take to be opened before timing out.
>   Current driver behavior already differs on this, so the default must be left to each driver. For new implementations, the default should be to never timeout.
>
> socketTimeoutMS=ms: How long a send or receive on a socket can take before timing out. 
>   Current driver behavior already differs on this, so the default must be left to each driver. For new implementations, the default should be to never timeout.